# How to get tkinter to focus in on entry box on initializing new window?

Tags: python, tkinter, tkinter-entry, setfocus

I am trying to use `tkinter` to create a new window with the focus set on its entry box. I am using the following code, which as far as I can tell should work:

```
import tkinter as tk

m = tk.Tk(className="My window")
def clickclack():
    new = tk.Tk(className="New")
    entr = tk.Entry(new)
    entr.grid()
    entr.focus_set()

butt = tk.Button(m, text="My button", width=25, command=clickclack)
butt.grid()
m.mainloop()
```

However, when I run it and click on the button, although a new window with an entry box pops up, the focus is not on it. I am not sure why `focus_set()` isn't working here, any help would be appreciated.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It is not recommend to use many `Tk` instance at the same time.Another window should use `Toplevel` instance.(Maybe will cause `StringVar()`(and so on) couldn't work normally).

Due to `Toplevel` didn't have attribute `className`,if you want to set the title name for the new window,you need to use `Toplevel().title("xxxxx")`.

Also,you could make your `Toplevel` focused firstly,then make your `Entry` widget focuesed.

Try:

```
import tkinter as tk

m = tk.Tk(className="My window")
def clickclack():
    new = tk.Toplevel()
    new.title("New") # set title
    entr = tk.Entry(new)
    entr.grid()
    new.focus() # make the window focused
    entr.focus()

butt = tk.Button(m, text="My button", width=25, command=clickclack)
butt.grid()
m.mainloop()
```

Answer (score 0):

I was able to solve my issue after finding [this gem](https://mail.python.org/pipermail/python-list/2002-October/151899.html) in some deep internet corner (AKA the fifth link of a google search). The simply solution is to use `focus_force()` instead of `focus_set()`. With all the rest of the code being equal, this simple change fixes everything.

Comment: As this said in the end *which 
is considered evil in many cases*.There is another way is make the window focused,then make your entry focused.And it is not recommend to use many `Tk()` instance at the same time.

Comment: @jizhihaoSAMA do you have a code example which implements that idea?

Answer (score 0):

You can try using the *focus()* function rather than *focus_set()*

```
entr = tk.Entry(new)
entr.grid()
entr.focus()
```

Comment: `focus()` gives me the same issue as `focus_set()`